# Proving a complex function is constant over a sophisticated set.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, complex-numbers

I need help proving he following statement:
If $f$ is an holomorphic  function over $A$ = { $z$ $\in$ $\Bbb C$ : $|z-10|$ < $10^{-10}$ } and we know that the image of this function is containe  in the line $Re$ $z$ = $-3$ then f is constant.

Im not looking for the straight answer I need help guiding me for answer the problem so dont get mad about it.

First , since whe want to prove $f$ is constant then we have to prove that $f'(z)=0$ over right?

Also , how does the hypothese the image of this function is containe  in the line $Re$ $z$ = $-3$  help us??

Thanks

Comment: HINT: Cauchy-Riemann's equations.

Comment: Better: holomorphic functions give open maps, hence if the image of an open disk belongs to a line, the function has to be constant.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that your function $f$ is analytic in $|z-10|\lt10$,and its image $f(z)$ lies on $Re(z)=-3$.It means that $f=-3+iv$,$v\in\mathbf R$ .So,Applying CR equations, $v_x=0$ and $v_y=0$ $\implies v $ is a real constant($k$,say).Hence,$f$ is constant in $|z-10|\lt10$.Hence proved!

Comment: $f$ is not real. The values are on the form $-3+it$, $t\in\mathbf R$.

Comment: @mickep,I edited it.

Comment: @mickep,Now the proof is correct.